# Show that X and Y are not independent

Tags: random-variables

Consider the probability space with $3$ possible outcomes, $a$, $b$, $c$, each of which occurs with probability $1/3$. Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are random variables such that $X(a) = −1$, $X(b) = 0$, $X(c) = 1$, and $Y(a) = 0$, $Y(b) = 1$, and $Y(c) = 0$.

Having hard time figuring out how to get $P(X(a))$. Isn't that what I need to prove that $P(X(a),Y(a)) \neq P(X(a))P(Y(a))$?

Answer (score 2):

To show that $X$ and $Y$ are not independent, you need to show that there are some sets $A$ and $B$, such that
$$P(X\in A, Y\in B)\neq P(X\in A)P(Y\in B).$$
We can try to take $A=B=\{0\}$. Looking at the right-hand-side first, we have
$$P(X\in A) = P(X=0) = P(\text{outcome } b) = \frac{1}{3},$$
since $b$ is the only outcome with $X(b) = 0$.
Similarly

$$P(Y\in B) = P(Y=0) = P(\text{outcome } a\text{ or }c)=\frac{2}{3}.$$
The right-hand-side is thus the product of these two numbers, i.e. $\frac{2}{9}$.
Let's look at the left-hand-side. We are looking at
$$P(X\in A, Y\in B) = P(X=0, Y=0).$$
We see that none of the outcomes $a$, $b$, or $c$ lets $X$ and $Y$ be equal to $0$ at the same time. Thus
$$P(X=0, Y=0) = 0,$$
which is different from $\frac{2}{9}$.

Comment: This was so clear. Thank you so much!